# LAS file bounding box is oversized after using lasnoise?

Tags: arcmap, lidar, extents, las, lastools

I have a few .las files that I am trying to use further. They have some far away noise points that I removed using LAStools `lasnoise`. It seems like the noise points are removed, but the bounding box for the files stays as big as they were.

Lasnoise settings here:

[image: lasnoise settings]

I created a LAS dataset out of the files, and you can see the big bounding boxes compared to the point locations. How do I make the bounding box smaller for easier usage. Or should `lasnoise` automatically scale the bounding box and something is not working right?

[image: bounding boxes in arcscene]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file's header might not have been updated after removing the noisy points.

1. In LAStools, run [lasinfo](http://lastools.org/download/lasinfo_README.txt) and check minimums and maximums for x, y and z coordinates in the **header**'s section of the report (it is the first report section: '*reporting all LAS header entries*').
2. Compare* them to the min. and max. coords from the point record section ('*reporting minimum and maximum for all LAS point record entries ...*'). *Multiply these for the **scale** factor and add the **offset** value, before comparing.
3. Also, take a look at the end of the report. It will warn if the bounding box is correct, or if there is a problem with it. [Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307541/using-lastools-to-repair-headers-for-several-lidar-files) you can see what a report from `lasinfo` looks like.
4. If coords do not match, run `lasinfo` again using the `-repair` parameter. It will fix (tight) the bounding box.

   ```
   lasinfo -i *.las -repair
   ```
5. Open the repaired file in ArcScene and check results.